# how to add custom js file to reactjs which is in public

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a js file which animated some html attribute using ids, which located in public folder of react project

is there any way to get those animations using react by loading this js file to react components ?

Comment: In order to answer your second question, you have to provide the code of the js file that you want to use. Is it a library? is it a custom js file made by you? why not use React's [CSS transition](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition/) or any other React library for this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found my my solution. It just load entire js file before component mount

```
componentWillMount = () => {
     loadjs('/js/file.js');
}
```

[For more details](https://github.com/muicss/loadjs)